# Postgres sql query code coverage

Tags: postgresql, code-coverage

We have embedded our postgres query in a Java webservice and we need a tool which examines the embedded query and gives us a code coverage report for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own custom build of PostgreSQL, using the `--enable-coverage` option on the `./configure` step.  To reset statistics for a fresh run, use `make coverage-clean`.

Basically, you can take [the example used for checking code coverage of the PostgreSQL regression test suite](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/regress-coverage.html) and substitute your own code for the `make check` step.